# Variable Interpolation in Vimscript catch clause

Tags: exception, vim

I'm working on a small testing framework for vim plugins and am trying to implement a function that calls a user-specified function and checks if the function calls exceptions when needed. The problem I'm having is that I can't get the vim catch clause to accept a string passed in to the testing function.

Here's a simplified version of what I'd like.

```
function! TestException(fx, arguments, exception)
    let Fx = function(a:fx)
    try
        call call(Fx, a:arguments)
    catch a:exception           " Here's the problem line
        return 1
    endtry
    return 0
endfunction
```

This function works fine if I hard code the exception into the catch clause

```
catch /E740/
```

or whatever, but it doesn't interpolate the passed in variable. I've tried executing the whole block in an 'execute' string, but that doesn't seem to work either.

So far I've tabled this issue and just allowed it to catch any exception and trust the caller to understand the limitation of that kind of general test.

So, does anybody know how to fix this, or, does anybody know of a way to figure out which exception was thrown after it's caught so I can compare that to the argument after the fact?

Comment: You could `catch` all exceptions, and then compare `v:exception` to `a:exception` to determine if the type matches. Your `/E740/` is a regular expression, possibly matching a substring of the complete exception. If you turn `a:exception` into a regular expression (or interpolate it into one), that might be a better solution, but I can't get it to work myself.

Comment: If your intent is test framework for Vim you should check [RunVimTests plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2565), which works very well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why use `match()`? There is `=~#` operator. Also note that

1. `a:exception` should not be just `E470`: it may be thrown by user. It should be `^Vim\%((\a\+)\)\=:E470` (regex taken from `:h :catch`).
2. You cannot `:throw` `Vim(call):E107: Missing parenthesis: abc`. `:execute` is really better in this case:

   ```
   function TestException(fx, arguments, exception)
       let d={}
       " XXX You must not ever use plain variables for holding
       "     function references because for every possible
       "     variable name it is possible to construct
       "         function Fx()
       "         endfunction
       "     definition that will prevent you from using this 
       "     variable.
       let d.Fx=function(a:fx)
       " Also note that for call() there is exactly no need in
       " using function references, call() accepts function names
       " as well. Thus I construct function reference above just
       " to write the above comment, but use a:fx in call() call
       " below.
       execute "try"
          \."\n   call call(a:fx, a:arguments, {})"
          \."\n   let r=0"
          \."\n catch /".a:exception."/"
          \."\n   let r=1"
          \."\n endtry"
       return r
   endfunction
   ```
3. Note about function references above. What will happen if you have function `Fx` is `E705: Variable name conflicts with existing function: Fx`.
4. Note about `call()` arguments above. If you remove `function()` call you may also pass `TestException` function function references. And if you add third argument (some dictionary, I usually use empty; these functions may or may not actually use `self` variable, but in any case require third argument) this will also allow anonymous functions while not doing any difference to non-anonymous non-dictionary function calls.
5. Note the `return r` and `let r=…`: I guess this is the error you found when creating your workaround (if I wrap this block keeping returns I always get zero). It also works if I replace `let r=…` with `return …` (note that `return 0` will be located inside `:try` block, not outside of it), but single exit point looks nicer.

Comment: I reported the problem described in 5. to vim-dev: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vim_dev/RMoXuHfYB5g.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I've incorporated most of what you suggest into my function but I wanted to address each point. 1. The /E740/ was simply an example of how I could get the old version to work, I totally agree that a better regex for exceptions should be used. 2. With your try block, now I don't even have to worry about this. 3 and 4. Great points and quite an oversight on my part. I've eliminated the need for a funcref completely. 5. Also a good point, but the version I posted really was simplified and I had not seriously planned on returning mid catch. Finally, forgot about =~#.

Answer (score 0):

Jim Stewart, that's the perfect workaround. I now have something like

```
function! TestException(fx, arguments, exception)
    let Fx = function(a:fx)
    try
        call call(Fx, a:arguments)
    catch
        if match(v:exception, a:exception) >= 0
             return 1
        else
             throw v:exception
        endif
    endtry
    return 0
endfunction
```

Vim doesn't like when you throw Vim exceptions manually, but it still lets the user know when another exception than the one expected was thrown. Can't believe I didn't notice v:exception.